# how manage the different sdk in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, virtual-reality, gear-vr, daydream

I want make an Andriod VR application that will be for **daydream**, **Gear VR** and some other devices. So, the SDKs are different and I need to manage the different types of camera and input modules. So is there a convenient way to manage it?

Comment: do you want all options in same application at once?

Comment: yes, if it could.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, you have required to manage different SDKs and unity also provide you to manage different sdk as its [VR overview](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VROverview.html) stated:

> Your built application initializes and enables devices in the same
>   order as the Virtual Reality SDKs list in Other Settings (see Enabling
>   VR Support, above). Devices not present in the list at build time are
>   not available in the final build. Device None is equivalent to a
>   non-VR application (that is, a normal Unity application) and can be
>   switched to during runtime without including it in the list; the
>   exception to this is None.

Probably the helpful API you need to consider are

[**VRSettings.LoadDeviceByName**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRSettings.LoadDeviceByName.html)

[**VRSettings.supportedDevices
Other Versions**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRSettings-supportedDevices.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could create different Unity projects and share the Assets directory with symbolic links.

- That way all your scripts, texture, models, scenes, etc. is automatically imported in all your different projects.
- If you make a change for example on your scene in one project, the other projects are also automatically updated with the change, yet you can have unique project/build/input/graphics settings for each project.

If you are working in Windows, I would recommend [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) to assist you with the symbolic link creation or see https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/ for the list of command line commands.

Otherwise for Linux the command is:
`ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink`